# Is this a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Is this a JSON array: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_ajax.php?

Source: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_ajax.txt

```
$urls = array(); foreach (glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/ico/*.gif') as $file) { $urls[] = 'http://flamencopeko.net/ico/' . basename($file); };

$index = 0;

if (isset($_GET['index'])) {
    $index = (int) $_GET['index'];

    if ($index > (count($urls) - 1)) {
        // Out of bounds, reset
        $index = 0;
    }
}

$previous = $index - 1;
$next = $index + 1;

if ($previous < 0) {
    $previous = count($urls) - 1;
}

if ($next == count($urls)) {
    $next = 0;
}

echo json_encode(array(
    'total' => count($urls),
    'url'   => $urls[$index],
    'next'  => $next,
    'prev'  => $previous,
    'alls' => $urls
));
```

I'm trying to use it with php. Works with JavaScript. I've tried json_decode() and more, but no output yet.

Comment: Does json_decode() output any errors ? And yes, this looks like JSON to me.

Comment: I'm not really sure exactly you mean, but that link seems like pretty valid JSON

Comment: No, it's not a JSON _array_, the array you're looking for is probably the `alls` property.

Comment: It's not an array. One property is an array though.

Comment: Yes, it's a JSON-encoded object.

Comment: You may use http://jsonlint.com/ for JSON validation

Comment: If you want to turn it back into an **array** (from an object) in PHP, you'll need to pass `true` (bool) into the second parameter of `json_decode`, otherwise you'll get an object

Comment: hindmost: Thanks. I was aware of http://jslint.com, although it has seldom helped me. I'll check out http://jsonlint.com now. Cool.

Comment: scrowler: Yes. That I happen to know. But thanks.

Comment: I see the logic in the whole thing being an object and the alls property or variable or what it is being the array. I tried `<?php 
echo (json_decode(icons_ajax.php?alls, true));
 ?>` and lots of other stuff.

Comment: André: Firebug outputs a lot of stuff. I'm not sure if it's JavaScript errors.

Comment: jsonlint.com says:

**Parse error on line 1:
$urls=array();foreac
^
Expecting '{', '['**

Any truth to this being an error?

Answer (score 1):

What you've shown is a JSON object. It contains an array inside, but the entire thing is an object. Think of it this way-JSON could be a key-value data, making it an object, or it could be an array-single values, no keys such as

```
[1,2,3,"some string",34,"another string"]
```

What you've shown is a completely valid JSON object. Whether it will suit your needs-we cannot say. You could take a look at [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for the exact specifications and what is considered a valid JSON.

Also any array passed on to `json_encode()` will output a valid JSON.

Comment: `echo (json_decode('icons_ajax.php?alls', true));` outputs nothing. Then again my code is more or less guesswork. Suggestions for how to convert to php array very welcome. Should I pass header() from http://flamencopeko.net/icons_ajax.php? I've tried that, but it didn't help.

Comment: Of course it wouldn't. `json_decode()` will not open a stream. What you need to do is fetch the contents first. In other words something like `var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('icons_ajax.php?alls'), true));`. Echo will output `Array()` so you need to use eirther `var_dump()` or `print_r()`

Comment: Ah. We should use both `json_decode` and `file_get_contents`. Very cool. Now I do get at least an error: 

Warning: file_get_contents(icons_ajax.php?alls) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/flamenco/public_html/icons_cogo_19.php on line 183
NULL

Comment: Could be because this executes before the JSON is fully loaded. Takes a long time with my noob code.

Comment: Any way to make PHP wait until the JSON is loaded? Looked around, found nothing.

Comment: well I gave a figurative example. I assume icons_ajax.php dynamically loads a JSON object, it's not a static content. You need to specify the path to where you are getting it from. Something like `var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('http://flamencopeko.net/icons_ajax.php?all'), true));` or something along those lines. If you don't specify a protocol(http, https, ftp, etc.), `file_get_contents()` will try to open a local file, on the server's filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the online json viewer at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ - which shows you have a valid json object; which you could use to see that it consists of some header info and an array of 406 images in the 'alls' array.

[image]