# PHP string array to php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this string array:

```
["652","110","111","1032","118","416","147","121","112","1033","113","1031","868"]
```

I need to read each value so to get

```
652
110
111
1032
```

i try to convert string array using explode and then foreach but is not working...

```
$channels = explode('"', $string_array);

foreach($channels as &$channel) {
    echo $channel.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Is it an array or string ?

Comment: This is a JSON string, use `json_decode()`.

Comment: It doesn't look like a JSON string to me, it looks like a php array literal.

Comment: How is this json string generated / where does it come from? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568420/properly-format-json-array-in-javascript

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21369519/2943403

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1515928/2943403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's an JSON format, so use json_decode

```
$json = '["652","110","111","1032","118","416","147","121","112","1033","113","1031","868"]';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($array AS $channel) {
    echo $channel.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: It gives an error

Comment: what the error you got?

Comment: missing your single quotes, to make it not a PHP array ;p

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: yes... put all the json string in single quotes ... i updated the code

Comment: OP  never mentioned it as a json string, not even tagged

Comment: It is obvious @RavinderReddy

Comment: how did you got this string?  this is the only option :)
if you need something else... i will be glad to help.

Comment: ok that makes sense.